# Pick's Theorem for rational points of bounded height

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry, rational-points

I wonder if the various lattice-point theorems, such as 
[Pick's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) or 
[Minkowski's Lattice Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem),
have been generalized to the collection of points
with rational coordinates no more than height $h$?

A rational $a/b$ in lowest terms has *height* $\max( |a|,|b| )$.
For example, here are the positive rationals of height $\le 5$:
$$\left\{\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},
\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{5},\frac
   {2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}
   {5},1,\frac{5}{4},\frac{4}{
   3},\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{3},
   2,\frac{5}{2},3,4,5 \right\}$$
(Incidentally, the length of this list is given 
by integer sequence [A018805](http://oeis.org/A018805).)

Let us call rationals of height $\le h$, *$h$-rationals*, 
and points with both coordinates $h$-rationals,
*$h$-rational points*
(my own terminology).
Generalizations from lattice points to $h$-rational points
seems natural, and likely
has been explored...? If so, I would appreciate a reference!
That's my primary question.

Here is a specific, Pick's Theorem -like question:

> Can the number $i$ of $h$-rational points inside a polygon $P$
>   be expressed in a form that is not tantamount to
>   enumerating each interior point?
>   Assume we are
>   given the vertex coordinates of $P$, and perhaps the number
>   of boundary points on each edge.

If $P$ is an axis-aligned rectangle, then the number of interior points $i$
can be computed from the number of points $b_x$ lying on the
bottom side and the number lying on the left side $b_y$:
$i = (b_x - 2)(b_y - 2)$. So, for the rectangle with lowerleft
corner $(1,1)$ below, $b_x=8$ and $b_y=7$ leads to $i=30$.
But just knowing the total number of boundary points $b=26$,
a la Pick's Theorem, is inadequate to determine $i$.
It seems feasible that there is a nonlinear transformation that
maps the $h$-rational points to the integer lattice, allowing
Pick's Theorem to be applied there.
Answering this question when $P$ is a triangle should lead to a result for arbitrary
$P$ via triangulation.

       
[image: RatsHeight5]

Comment: Why do you not include negative rational numbers or $0$ when you illustrate the count on the number of rational points with height at most 5?

Comment: @KConrad: Just an arbitrary decision, matching A018805.

Comment: But the count of all rational numbers with height at most $n$ is *not* that online sequence.

Comment: @KConrad: You are right. I corrected the sentence to say the *positive* rational numbers of height at most $h$. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that there can be any formula nearly as nice as Pick's here.
You're asking for primitive integer points in a 3-dim.
polyhedron (intersection of the cube $|x|\leq H, |y|\leq H, |z|\leq H$
with the polyhedral cone 
$\lbrace x,y,z \in {\bf R}^3 : (x/z,y/z) \in P \rbrace$).
Even without the primitivity condition, the formulas are somewhat complicated, 
even when as here some of the polyhedron's sides are parallel to the 
coordinate axes; and the primitive subset surely cannot be any *easier* 
to enumerate when the asymptotic behavior as $H\rightarrow\infty$ includes a factor
$1/\zeta(3)$ !

Answer (score 2):

One can at least give an asymptotic behaviour of this number, when the height bound grows to infinity.

As shown by Emmanuel Peyre in his paper, *Hauteurs et mesures de Tamagawa sur les variétés de Fano* (Duke Math. J, **79**), there are cases of algebraic varieties over a number field where one can prove an equidistribution statement for the points of bounded height, and the projective space is such a case.

Here is a consequence of that theorem, for the case of the projective line $\mathbf P^1_{\mathbf Q}$. Since you normalized the height of a point $p/q\in\mathbf P^1(\mathbf Q)$ to be $\max(|p|,|q|)$, when written in lower terms, let us define a measure on $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf R)=\mathbf R\cup\{\infty\}$  by $\mu=\mathrm dt/\max(1,|t|)^2$. (For an explanation of the exponent $2$ in the definition of the measure $\mu$, observe that the differential form $\mathrm dt$ has a pole of order $2$ at infinity.)

For any subset $U$ of $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf R)$, let $N(U;B)$ be the number of points of $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf Q)$ of height $\leq B$ which belong to $U$.
Peyre's Theorem asserts that for any open subset $U$ of $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf R)$ whose boundary has  $\mu$-measure $0$, the following limit formula holds:
   $$ \frac{N(U;B)}{N(\mathbf P^1(\mathbf R);B)} \to \frac{\mu(U)}{\mu(\mathbf P^1(\mathbf R))} $$
when $B\to\infty$.

The actual statement holds at an adelic level, and for more general normalization of the height, for any number field, as well as for more general varieties.